# How to store in a register the address of an element of an array in asm?

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

```
#include <stdio.h> 
void main()

{
//Variables

char string[] = "This is a string";

_asm {
    XOR EAX, EAX
    XOR EBX, EBX
    XOR ECX, ECX

    MOV EAX, [string]

}
```

What I'm trying to do is store the memory address of the first element of string in EAX but I get "Operand size conflict" . I'm guessing the syntax for dereference is wrong since both eax and the memory adress should be 32 bits, but I can't find anything about it on stack overflow

this is on visual studio done with _asm in C

Comment: You should state what compiler and assembler you are using, since inline assembly details vary greatly between them.  This looks like a Visual C++-type compiler with perhaps a MASM assembler underneath, so you probably want `MOV EAX, OFFSET string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MOV EAX, [string] is not going to work because char is 8 bit and eax is 32 bit register just use [LEA](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LEA.html) load effective address:

```
LEA EAX, [string]
```

NOTE: what LEA does is converting var to offset so the compiler see it like this: `LEA MOV, [offset point to address]`